# Why doesn't the NMOS 6502 have the illegal instruction, STA immediate?

Tags: 6502, undocumented-opcodes

The 6502's instructions have the form `aaa-bbb-cc`, where `cc` picks an instruction group. Group `01` is the most regular and easy to understand. In this group, `aaa` picks an instruction from the list

- 000   ORA
- 001   AND
- 010   EOR
- 011   ADC
- 100   STA
- 101   LDA
- 110   CMP
- 111   SBC

and `bbb` picks an addressing mode, from the list:

- 000   (zero page,X)
- 001   zero page
- 010   #immediate
- 011   absolute
- 100   (zero page),Y
- 101   zero page,X
- 110   absolute,Y
- 111   absolute,X

so this question is about the opcode `10001001`, which is $89 in hexadecimal. This looks as though it *could've* encoded `STA #imm`, but it doesn't.

Now, the 6502 famously has many undefined opcodes which have been used by actual software, especially in the Commodore 64 demoscene and other places. These arise from the partial decoding of the opcode. It is known that the engineers who made the 6502 did not waste any logic trying to do some kind of illegal instruction trap or anything like that. So in my eyes, I think this instruction should just have the immediate addressing mode, just like any `xxx-010-01` instruction, and also store the accumulator, like any `100-xxx-01` instruction. Obviously, it would not have been useful. But would have arisen from a straight-forward encoding of the `01` group.

So in [a reference of illegal opcodes](http://wouter.bbcmicro.net/general/6502/6502_opcodes_illegal.html) $89 appears to be `NOP zp`, which I imagine reads a byte from the zero page and ignores it.

I wonder why this instruction doesn't actually store the accumulator in the byte immediately after the fetched opcode. As I recall, the related 6800 and 6801 have an illegal store immediate instruction. But not the 6502. Was there a deliberate effort to avoid this instruction?

Comment: The concept of "store immediate" is pretty strange to modern-day sensibilities... but you're right, it would make perfect sense that it would store the accumulator into the immediate value slot after the instruction.

Comment: @user253751 is it? x86 got them. Also, what slot is there after the instruction?

Comment: @Raffzahn I mean the byte(s) after the instruction, where the immediate value is. No, x86 does not have "store immediate"

Comment: @user253751 After an instruction is the next instruction. And of course does x86 have a store immediate. It's even in the very basic single opcode range:  `C6` will move an immediate byte, while `C7` does the same for a word. Thus `C6 06 23 01 FF` will move the immediate value of FFh into the byte memory at 0123h.  in 32 bit mode C7 will ofc do 32 bit words. It's a very handy instruction, available with several CPU - including the Z80 :))

Comment: @Raffzahn After the opcode, to be pedantic. Storing an immediate value to an address specified by an immediate value is not in any way the same as storing a register **to the immediate value itself** which is what this hypothetical `STA #` instruction would do.

Comment: @Raffzahn well that's what this question is asking about, isn't it!!

Comment: @user253751 as I read it, the question asks why that opcode doesn't perform (in some way or another) like this, not if that is a useful or doable instruction, or how it should perform. And the answer to that is simply that the instruction does not exist as the ROM decodes it as a NOP with an immediate parameter (which gets discarded).

Comment: @Raffzahn and I did not question how it should perform, merely commented it would be a very strange instruction if it did perform the obvious way. Why are you arguing?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Applying the same decoding logic to $89 as is applied to $85, $A9, and $A5 would result in an instruction whose external behavior would match LDA #imm, but which doesn't update any registers or flags.  Not coincidentally, an NMOS 6502 behaves in exactly that fashion.

The 6502 generally decides what operation is going to be doing on each memory cycle before the end of the read of the previous cycle; the primary exception to this is that "perform an operation with a specified low address, along with a high address fetched from the data bus" and "perform an operation with a specified high address, along with a low address fetched from the data bus" are available as operation choices(*)

The distinctions among `LDA #imm`, `LDA zp`, and `STA zp` are all made while the second byte of the instruction is being fetched.  This is fine for any instruction which would read an immediate operand, since the CPU will know what to do with the data by the time it arrives on the bus at the end of the second cycle.  In order for `STA #imm` to work, however, the CPU would have to know before the beginning of the second cycle that it would need to perform a write.  There's no way the CPU can go back in time after it has fetched the operand byte and retroactively change that read to a write.  While it might be theoretically possible to have the instruction insert a write cycle, doing so would eliminate any benefit that `STA #imm` could have offered over `STA zp`.  If `STA #imm`, `STX #imm`, and `STY #imm` could execute in two cycles each, that could reduce the cost of saving registers on interrupt entry by three cycles compared with using zero-page forms.  If the instructions existed but took three cycles each, however, using zero-page forms would be just as fast but more convenient.

Another way of looking at things might be to say that immediate mode doesn't instruct the processor to fetch the byte after the opcode and do something with it, but instead instructs the processor that logic which would normally fetch a memory operand into a temporary register should instead do nothing, leaving that register holding *a byte that was blindly fetched without knowing what if anything it would be used for*.  Store instruction piggy-back on the memory-access logic used for other instructions, except that they assert R/W during what would otherwise be the final memory fetch.  Since the memory-access logic does nothing during LDA #imm, it likewise does nothing during STA #imm.

(*) These are, of course, fundamental to the efficient operation of the machine, since in most programs, the majority of cycles that aren't code fetches will fit one of those patterns.   When processing `LDA (zp),y`, for example, the third cycle combines a zero high byte with a newly-fetched low byte, and the fifth combines a newly-computed low byte with a newly-fetched high byte).  Of the cycles that aren't code fetches, only the fourth cycle and (if present) sixth cycle won't load half of the address bus with newly-fetched data.

Comment: @Raffzahn: What do you mean "not including the reason"?  In order for the 6502 to process `STA #imm` as a store, it would have to be able to select whether the second cycle is a read or write based upon the value that was read in the first cycle, but the 6502's circuitry will already be committed to performing a read on the second cycle before data from the first cycle is available.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "change that *read* to a *write*" in the second paragraph?

Comment: @MichaelGraf:" Thanks.  Corrected.  The key point is that by the time the 6502 could know that it should do a write on the second cycle to avoid having to do one later, the opportunity to do so without wasting a cycle would have passed.

Comment: I upvoted, but I found the answer pretty confusing. I didn't understand where the explanation was going until the first sentence of paragraph 3. I wonder if you could summarize at the top, perhaps along the lines of "there is separate instruction-fetching and data-access logic, and immediate operands are handled by the instruction-fetching logic, which only does reads"—assuming that is accurate.

Comment: @supercat you're trying to explain this by adding meta reasoning - something a CPU doesn't do. This may be used to explain why someone want to have that behaviour, but not why the CPU is working that way.

Comment: @benrg: The issue isn't that there's separate logic, but rather that the CPU's decision of what to do on the cycle following an opcode fetch must be made before the CPU can know what the opcode will be.  The designers of the 6502 decided to use that cycle to perform a fetch of the byte following the opcode, on the basis that doing so would be useful most of the time, and would almost always be harmless even in cases where it isn't useful (it could cause problems if e.g. address $BFFF held an RTS and address $C000 was mapped to read-triggered I/O, but such issues would be rare).

Comment: @Raffzahn: If the designers of the 6502 had thought store immediate would be useful, there are two approaches they could have taken to supporting it.  Supporting two-cycle store-immediate instructions while satisfying timing constraints would likely have been possible but expensive.  Supporting three-cycle store-immediate instructions would have been cheaper, but the time penalty would undermine the usefulness of those instructions.  In neither approach would the benefit offered by the approach exceed the cost thereof.

Answer (score 8):

### TL;DR:

> Why doesn't the NMOS 6502 have the illegal instruction, STA immediate?

It doesn't, because $89 is none of the undecoded ('illegal') operations, but decoded as NOP by design.

> So in a reference of illegal opcodes $89 appears to be NOP zp, which I imagine reads a byte from the zero page and ignores it.

That reference seems off. [$89 is a NOP #imm](https://www.nesdev.org/wiki/Programming_with_unofficial_opcodes#NOPs), much like already implied by your question. It's executed in two cycles, there is no ZP access of any kind.

> As I recall, the related 6800 and 6801 have an illegal store immediate instruction

That would be the [infamous STA* instructions](https://spivey.oriel.ox.ac.uk/wiki/images-corner/1/1a/Undoc6800.pdf) (*1), except that these do not store the value into the immediate field of the instruction, but *after* the instruction, at the location where the next instruction would be - except execution continues after that (*2). The immediate value gets ignored.

> Obviously, it would not have been useful.

Not really, so why should they have bothered to implement it, as doing so would have needed to add at least one (more like two or three) additional ROM entries (*3).

---

### So Why Is It That Way

When it comes to the 'illegal' opcodes (*4) it helps to differentiate between the 'tamed' ones and the 'wild' beasts. The differentiation becomes quite obvious when looking at the opcode chart:

[image: Opcode Chart with 'illegal' opcodes grouped]

*(Taken from Norbert Landsteiner's [6502 "Illegal" Opcodes Demystified](https://www.masswerk.at/nowgobang/2021/6502-illegal-opcodes) page - with some colouring added (*5))*

By marking the various types of undefined opcodes it becomes clear that there are three different groups:

- **The Good** (Green) are in tamed as NOPs by design
- **The Bad** (Red) are the wild ones everbody talks about
- **The Ugly** (Pink), sending the CPU into an infinite T1 loop

**The questioned $89 falls into the green group.** They are well decoded withing their group (CC=00/01/10) and executed as NOP by design, because they do not make any sense - $80, `STY #imm`, is a similar case.

There are two exceptions to this, $8C SHY abs,X and $8E SHX abs,y (*6)

**The read ones**, mix up functionality from other groups as their group (CC=11) is simply not decoded at all. They are the real orphans of the 6500 design - and like orphans they look for surrogate parents in group CC=01 and 10 (*7).

**The pink group** in turn are somewhat similar. While their group line (CC=10) is decoded, there are no entries in the decode ROM except for AAA=1xx BBB=x00 (light green), which gives that $A2, `LDX #imm` its 3 siblings work as intended. Having no entries makes them stuck in a never ending T1 cycle, reading the second byte over and over until freed by RESET.

**Bottom line: $89 has been made a NOP on purpose by design.** It might be undefined, but is not really a member of the 'illegal' bunch.

---

*1 - STAA ($87), STAB ($C7), STX ($8F) and STS ($CF), each being two byte opcodes with the second byte being ignored, store their register *after* the instruction and continue with execution thereafter. This means the STA* variant would be a 3 byte structure, where the value of A or B would be stored in the third, while ST* would be 4 bytes storing IX or SP into bytes 3 (low) and 4 (high).

*2 - Now, that would have been a quite interesting use case for self modifying code, kind of an [EX-instruction](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/360_Assembly/360_Instructions/EX) where the to be executed instruction had to be prepared in an accumulator, for single byte, or IX, for two byte instructions. Not that it would have saved code or make it more elegant, just interesting.

*3 - It would at least need to suppress the increment of the PC, like done with a NOP, during the second cycle, followed by the store and an increment after the store, so maybe 3 additional lines or ~2.5% additional ROM for an instruction with rather dubious usability?

*4 - Naming is a real crux here, as the term 'illegal' implies something that not really exists in an instruction set. Opcodes *not defined*  to carry out some operation (aka 'unused') are simply that: *Undefined/Unused Opcodes*.

The story could end here, except that the 6500 design added an additional pitfall by not straight making all unused do nothing (like the 65C02 later corrected), but some of them were left undecoded, resulting in additional functionality. Not intended but deterministic - as long as thedcoder was not changed.

*5 - [Norbert Landsteiner's page](https://www.masswerk.at/nowgobang/2021/6502-illegal-opcodes) goes way beyond [listing the 'illegal' opcodes](https://www.nesdev.org/undocumented_opcodes.txt), but dives deep into the structure, following Neil Parkers well known [The 6502/65C02/65C816 Instruction Set Decoded](https://llx.com/Neil/a2/opcodes.html)

*6 - Personally I would see them as leftover/unfinished implementation of `STY abs,X` and `STX abs,Y`, but that might be a different story.

*7 - I know that this is due the way that the groups are decoded into three select lines within the decoder and 11 simply activating the group 1 (CC=01) line as well as the group 2 (CC=10) line. adding one gate here could have prevented all of that and saved us all the hype about 'secret' opcodes and so on.

Comment: How do we know the ‘green’ NOPs are by design? Is there a design document confirming them as such?

Comment: @user3840170 Well, is there one that tells otherwise? Beside, looking at the decode ROM  does show that there are default entries that let them terminate that way - as usual, code is documentation :))=

Comment: Opcodes of the form xxx0 mm01, including 1000 1001, all behave identically prior to the cleanup cycle, save for the fact that 1000 mm01 turns the last post-decode read, *if any are done* into a write with the accumulator on the bus.  Instructions of the form xxx0 1001, including 1000 1001, all advance the program counter during the operand fetch, and then proceed to the cleanup/start next operation state without doing any post-decode reads, leaving the value that was fetched during the cycle after the opcode fetch in the temporary register.

Comment: @Raffzahn, it might improve your answer to include a relevant snippet from the microcode, showing STA immediate being "dummied out".

Comment: I suspect the change in how the 65C02 handles undefined opcodes was motivated by the fact that it's CMOS.  In NMOS, if something will pull down a signal in all cases where it needs to be low, and nothing will pull it down in cases where it needs to be high, one can ignore cases where the value doesn't matter.  In CMOS, one must identify all cases where nothing will pull down a signal and ensure that it gets pulled up in those cases, even it would have been acceptable for the signal to be pulled down instead.

Answer (score 3):

For me, the instruction:

STA #$00

as an example, makes no sense.  Where does $00 get stored?  There is no address.  Compare that with:

LDA #$00

Which loads the immediate value of $00 into the A register.

All the STA instructions use an addressing mode other than immediate which is not applicable for any register.

Your proposal for storing the immediate value in the address after the opcode would result in either "self-modifying code" if running out of RAM or basically a NOP, as was almost always the case, if the code was in ROM.

Because of this the designers of the 6502 simply did not decode that opcode even though they could have and, as you noted, trapped it or even done something else with it.  But the design goals of the team were make make a part that would be an order of magnitude less expensive than what was on the market at that time.  In order to be successful, and they were, the hardware design had to be as minimal as possible.

Comment: Of course the instruction makes no sense, but the question was why did they seem to go through the effort to remove it. The 6800 designers just left it there, and left it undocumented. I'm asking why the 6502 designers didn't do the same

Comment: There have been places I would have used the instruction had it existed.  Interrupt entry time could have been reduced by three cycles versus using zero-page mode if the interrupt vector jumped to RAM containing STA #x / STX #x / STY #x.  The reason the instructions don't seem to be decoded is, I think, that any such decoding would occur after the CPU has already committed itself to the second cycle being a read.

Comment: RE: "Where does $00 get stored?",  `STA` doesn't store its operand, it stores the accumulator. You'd expect a STA immediate to store the accumulator in the byte following the opcode, orthogonally to all other stores and to all other immediates.

Comment: @OmarL is that so? I would expect a STA #IMM to store the value, which is in the second byte into an address. Otherwise it'll be a STA ZP.

Comment: @OmarL: *All* instructions on the 6502 have the same behavior during the first two cycles, save only for the fact that some do not modify PC during the second.  The logic for processing an immediate mode operand isn't "fetch a byte at the PC address and increment PC", but rather "don't bother doing anything to fetch an operand, since it will already have been fetched by the time the instruction was decoded".

Comment: @Raffzahn: If the bytes at address $1000 and $1001 were $89 and xx, respectively, the accumulator held yy, and the 6502 were to execute the instruction at address $1000, I would expect that after "STA #imm"--if it were supported--address $1001 would hold yy and the program counter would be ready to fetch code from address $1002.

Comment: @supercat that's your assumption. I for one can not see that the PC is a valid source for a destination address.

Comment: @Raffzahn: I said *if it (i.e. the use of store-immediate) were supported*.  Supporting store-immediate instruction would require adding an expedited logic path to detect opcode pattern 1000 10xx and assert R/W in case it is, and maybe adding an expedited logic path for the register value (the data can tolerate an extra half cycle of propagation delay versus the R/W line).  If that were done, existing address-generation hardware could be used without modification, so the lack of special hardware for PC-based addressing would be a non-issue.

Comment: I think this is an answer. It answers the titular question; contradicting the question body's assertion of "But would have arisen from a straight-forward encoding of the `01` group." might make it a _wrong_ answer (I don't know; I have no subject matter expertise), but that's what downvotes are for.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Not sure. IMHO it does not really tackle the question. The question is why a certain non existing Operation doesn't perform what one might assume from knowing that undecoded 6502 instructions often perform part of what would happen at that code position if decoding  is assumed regular. **But the answer muses if that instruction would be useful or not** - something already denied by the Question asked. So it's not wrong (can't be wrong when talking about unknown), but simply missing the topic set by the question. Thus some might see it as not useful in this context.

Comment: @Raffzahn The last paragraph answers the title question, I think. Q: Why doesn't this chip have this instruction? A: "Because of […] the designers of the 6502 simply did not decode that opcode".

Comment: @wizzwizz4 This does sound like an assumption about a certain decision made back then, not why the CPU operates the way it does.

Comment: @Raffzahn Final sentence of the question: “Was there a deliberate effort to avoid this instruction?”; answers about the decision-making process are answers to the question, as written.

Comment: STA #00 makes sense. A gets copied to the immediate field of the instruction; and another instruction can retrieve it later.

Comment: @Joshua, but the electronics doesn't exist to do that in this CPU.